# Monad equivalent in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, monads

What would an equivalent construct of a monad be in Ruby?

Comment: A monad. Why would it be something different?

Comment: For exception handling, have a look at the examples in my gem https://github.com/pzol/monadic

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**The precise technical definition**: A monad, in Ruby, would be any class  with `bind` and `self.unit` methods defined such that for all instances m:

```
m.class.unit[a].bind[f] == f[a]
m.bind[m.class.unit] == m  
m.bind[f].bind[g] == m.bind[lambda {|x| f[x].bind[g]}]
```

**Some practical examples**

A very simple example of a monad is the lazy Identity monad, which emulates lazy semantics in Ruby (a strict language):

```
class Id
  def initialize(lam)
    @v = lam
  end

  def force
    @v[]
  end

  def self.unit
    lambda {|x| Id.new(lambda { x })}
  end

  def bind
    x = self
    lambda {|f| Id.new(lambda { f[x.force] })}
  end
end
```

Using this, you can chain procs together in a lazy manner. For example, in the following, `x` is a container "containing" `40`, but the computation is not performed until the second line, evidenced by the fact that the `puts` statement doesn't output anything until `force` is called:

```
x = Id.new(lambda {20}).bind[lambda {|x| puts x; Id.unit[x * 2]}]
x.force
```

A somewhat similar, less abstract example would be a monad for getting values out of a database. Let's presume that we have a class `Query` with a `run(c)` method that takes a database connection `c`, and a constructor of `Query` objects that takes, say, an SQL string. So `DatabaseValue` represents a value that's coming from the database. DatabaseValue is a monad:

```
class DatabaseValue
  def initialize(lam)
    @cont = lam
  end

  def self.fromQuery(q)
    DatabaseValue.new(lambda {|c| q.run(c) })
  end

  def run(c)
    @cont[c]
  end

  def self.unit
    lambda {|x| DatabaseValue.new(lambda {|c| x })}
  end

  def bind
    x = self
    lambda {|f| DatabaseValue.new(lambda {|c| f[x.run(c)].run(c) })}
  end
end
```

This would let you chain database calls through a single connection, like so:

```
q = unit["John"].bind[lambda {|n|
  fromQuery(Query.new("select dep_id from emp where name = #{n}")).
    bind[lambda {|id|
      fromQuery(Query.new("select name from dep where id = #{id}"))}].
        bind[lambda { |name| unit[doSomethingWithDeptName(name)] }]

begin
  c = openDbConnection
  someResult = q.run(c)
rescue
  puts "Error #{$!}"
ensure
  c.close
end
```

OK, so why on earth would you do that? Because there are extremely useful functions that can be written once *for all monads*. So code that you would normally write over and over can be reused for any monad once you simply implement `unit` and `bind`. For example, we can define a Monad mixin that endows all such classes with some useful methods:

```
module Monad
  I = lambda {|x| x }

  # Structure-preserving transform that applies the given function
  # across the monad environment.
  def map
    lambda {|f| bind[lambda {|x| self.class.unit[f[x]] }]}
  end

  # Joins a monad environment containing another into one environment.
  def flatten
    bind[I]
  end

  # Applies a function internally in the monad.
  def ap
    lambda {|x| liftM2[I,x] }
  end

  # Binds a binary function across two environments.
  def liftM2
    lambda {|f, m|
      bind[lambda {|x1|
        m.bind[lambda {|x2|
          self.class.unit[f[x1,x2]]
        }]
      }]
    }
  end
end
```

And this in turn lets us do even more useful things, like define this function:

```
# An internal array iterator [m a] => m [a]
def sequence(m)
  snoc = lambda {|xs, x| xs + [x]}
  lambda {|ms| ms.inject(m.unit[[]], &(lambda {|x, xs| x.liftM2[snoc, xs] }))}
end
```

The `sequence` method takes a class that mixes in Monad, and returns a function that takes an array of monadic values and turns it into a monadic value containing an array. They could be `Id` values (turning an array of Identities into an Identity containing an array), or `DatabaseValue` objects (turning an array of queries into a query that returns an array), or functions (turning an array of functions into a function that returns an array), or arrays (turning an array of arrays inside-out), or parsers, continuations, state machines, or anything else that could possibly mix in the `Monad` module (which, as it turns out, is true for almost all data structures).

Comment: Awesome explanation! Just a question: this seems to be a very functional implementation of Monads. In a more object-oriented implementation, wouldn't `unit` just be `new`? (Actually, I see now that the types don't quite match up. So, the more interesting question would be: is there a way to make `unit` be `new`? And what would object-orientation look like when we did it the other way round: make `new` behave like `unit`?)

Comment: Well, it would be equivalent if `new` satisfied the left and right unit laws. Unfortunately, methods, procs, and blocks aren't really all the same thing in Ruby, and importantly, *new is a side-effect*.

I think what I've shown here is a pretty "OO" encoding of monads in Ruby. There's another way of expressing the same data structures without using any classes at all except Proc, and that would be the "very functional" implementation.

I don't think that "object-oriented" has any precise meaning anyway, so I take the position of just not thinking about it.

Comment: Okay, so you lost me right after the first example because your `Id` class doesn't follow your "precise technical definition". Using `a = 10`, `m = Id.new(lambda { 5 })`, `f = lambda { |x| x.even? ? x/2 : 0 }`, and `g = lambda { |x| x * 2 }`, all three conditions fail. The closest I can get is `m.class.unit[a].bind[f].force == f[a]`, `m.bind[m.class.unit].force.force == m.force` and the third errors when calling `bind` on `0`.

Comment: Kache: Your `f` has the wrong type. It should return an `Id`.

Comment: Then if you already have an existing class `Foo` that have a set of functions FooFuncs that operate on `Foo`s, composing FooFuncs using monads would require defining a `FooMonad` class that wraps `Foo` and reimplements each FooFunc as FooMonad.wrap(FooFunc(Foo))? e.g. for FixNum, you'd have to reimplement +, *, /, even?, etc, as plus_wrapped, mult_wrapped, div_wrapped, even_wrapped, etc?

Comment: No, you can lift any existing function into a monad using `map` which is `bind(lambda { |x| unit[f[x]] })`

Comment: i.e. Using your implementation of `map`, a plus_wrapped could/would be defined/implemented as MonadClassInstance.map(plus_func)?

Comment: Not quite, since `plus` takes two arguments. So it would have to be `liftM2(plus_func)`.

Comment: Try the deterministic gem which implements all the common monads like Either, Maybe, Result in a rubyesque way https://github.com/pzol/deterministic

Answer (score 6):

To add my two cents, I'd say that hzap has misunderstood the concept of monads.
It's not only a « type interface » or a « structure providing some specific functions », it's muck more than that.
It's an abstract structure providing operations (bind (>>=) and unit (return)) which follow, as Ken and Apocalisp said, strict rules.

If you're interested by monads and want to know more about them than the few things said in these answers, I strongly advise you to read : [Monads for functional programming](http://rsz.me/baastad) (pdf), by Wadler.

See ya!

PS: I see I don't directly answer your question, but Apocalisp already did, and I think (at least hope) that my precisions were worth it

Answer (score 5):

Monads are not language constructs. They're just types that implement a particular interface, and since Ruby is dynamically typed, any class that implement something like `collect` in arrays, a join method (like `flatten` but only flattens one level), and a constructor that can wrap anything, is a monad.

Comment: It has to implement them correctly, so that they obey the monad laws.

Answer (score 1):

Following on the above answers:

You may be interested in checking out [Rumonade, a ruby gem which implements a Monad mix-in for Ruby](https://github.com/ms-ati/rumonade).

Romande is implemented as mix-in, so it expect its host class to implement the methods `self.unit` and `#bind` (and optionally, `self.empty`), and will do the rest to make things work for you.

You can use it to `map` over `Option`, as you are used to in Scala, and you can even get some nice [multiple-failure return values from validations](https://github.com/ms-ati/rumonade/wiki/Applicative-Validation-in-Ruby), a la Scalaz's Validation class.